# R Shiny: Error in serverFuncSource() : server.R returned an object of unexpected type: list

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build my first shiny app and have borrowed heavily from available templates. Unfortunately when I run the application, it flashes up briefly before crashing. The associated error message is:

> Error in serverFuncSource() : server.R returned an object of
>   unexpected type: list

What is causing this error and how can I fix it (have had no luck with searches online). The error message is frustratingly vague.

```
require(shiny)

ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("NFL"),
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("Margin", "Current margin", min=-50, max=50, value=0, step=1),
      textInput("Spread", "Spread", value=0, width="30%"),
      radioButtons("Quarter", "Current period", choices=c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "OT"), 
                         selected = "1st", inline = TRUE,width = NULL),
      textInput("TimeRemaining", "Time remaining (mm:ss)", value="15:00",  width="30%"),
      radioButtons("Down", "Down", choices=c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "N/A"), inline = TRUE),
      textInput("YTG", "Yards to go", value=10,  width="30%"),
      textInput("YFOG", "Yards from own goal", value=50,  width="30%"),
      checkboxGroupInput("Timeouts_Off", "Timeouts: Offense", choices=c("1", "2", "3")),
      checkboxGroupInput("Timeouts_Def", "Timeouts: Defence", choices=c("1", "2", "3"))
      ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('table')
    )
  )

server=function(input, output){
  x=matrix(0, nrow=1, ncol=11)
  colnames(x)=c("mar", "timeRemaining", "dwn.1", "dwn.2", "dwn.3", "dwn.4", "ytg","yfog", "closingLine", "timo", "timd")

  qtr=switch(input$Quarter, "1st"=1, "2nd"=2,"3rd"=3,"4th"=4, "OT"=5)
  mins=substr(input$TimeRemaining,1,2)
  secs=substr(input$TimeRemaining,4,5)
  timeLeft=100-10/6*((4-qtr)*15+(mins+secs/60))

  x[1,1]=input$Margin
  x[1,2]=timeLeft
  x[1,3]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=1, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=0,"4th"=0)
  x[1,4]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=1,"3rd"=0,"4th"=0)
  x[1,5]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=1,"4th"=0)
  x[1,6]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=0,"4th"=1)
  x[1,7]=input$YTG
  x[1,8]=input$YFOG
  x[1,9]=input$spread
  x[1,10]=input$Timeouts_Off
  x[1,11]=input$Timeouts_Def

  #x=data.frame(x)
  xsq=select(x,mar:timd, -dwn.1, -dwn.2, -dwn.3, -dwn.4)^2
  colnames(xsq)=paste(colnames(xsq), "sq",  sep = "_")
  xln=log(select(x,timeRemaining:timd, -closingLine, -dwn.1, -dwn.2, -dwn.3, -dwn.4))
  colnames(xln)=paste(colnames(xln), "ln",  sep = "_")
  x=cbind(x, xsq, xln)
  rm(xln, xsq)
  x
  output$table <- renderTable(x)
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `x = data.matrix(0, nrow=1, ncol=11)`

Comment: just creating an empty matrix to populate later

Comment: did you try running this line. From where you got the arguments `nrow, ncol` for `data.matrix()`

Comment: Use `matrix()`, other than this, you need to wrap your code in `reactive()`

Comment: thanks for the data.matrix pick-up. Fixed now. Can you explain what you mean by wrapping in reactive()? I am still getting the same error message as before.

Comment: Posted the code below

Answer (score 4):

Got this bug using a shiny app (with 3 files, not all in one file like it is here) by accidentally copying ui.R code into server.R

Comment: This isn't related to your specific question on your app, but considering that this was the first question a search for this bug returned, other people may find this answer helpful since it may resolve an issue with the same bug in the title of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Few things I noticed:

1) The line you used in your code `x = data.matrix(0, nrow=1, ncol=11)` is a source of error. To create matrix use `x = matrix(0, nrow=1, ncol=11)`.

2) Its not allowed to use the code in shiny without wrapping in a `reactive()` function, which is the reason of other error. For more `?reactive`, `?eventReactive`

After fixing these two issues, the code does not give any error. However, you need to check for the proper functioning of the code. Find the working code below.

```
require(shiny)

ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("NFL"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("Margin", "Current margin", min=-50, max=50, value=0, step=1),
    textInput("Spread", "Spread", value=0, width="30%"),
    radioButtons("Quarter", "Current period", choices=c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "OT"), 
                 selected = "1st", inline = TRUE,width = NULL),
    textInput("TimeRemaining", "Time remaining (mm:ss)", value="15:00",  width="30%"),
    radioButtons("Down", "Down", choices=c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "N/A"), inline = TRUE),
    textInput("YTG", "Yards to go", value=10,  width="30%"),
    textInput("YFOG", "Yards from own goal", value=50,  width="30%"),
    checkboxGroupInput("Timeouts_Off", "Timeouts: Offense", choices=c("1", "2", "3")),
    checkboxGroupInput("Timeouts_Def", "Timeouts: Defence", choices=c("1", "2", "3"))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput('table')
  )
)

server=function(input, output){
  out <- reactive({
  x=matrix(0, nrow=1, ncol=11)
  colnames(x)=c("mar", "timeRemaining", "dwn.1", "dwn.2", "dwn.3", "dwn.4", "ytg","yfog", "closingLine", "timo", "timd")

  qtr=switch(input$Quarter, "1st"=1, "2nd"=2,"3rd"=3,"4th"=4, "OT"=5)
  mins=substr(input$TimeRemaining,1,2)
  secs=substr(input$TimeRemaining,4,5)
  timeLeft=100-10/6*((4-qtr)*15+(mins+secs/60))

  x[1,1]=input$Margin
  x[1,2]=timeLeft
  x[1,3]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=1, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=0,"4th"=0)
  x[1,4]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=1,"3rd"=0,"4th"=0)
  x[1,5]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=1,"4th"=0)
  x[1,6]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=0,"4th"=1)
  x[1,7]=input$YTG
  x[1,8]=input$YFOG
  x[1,9]=input$spread
  x[1,10]=input$Timeouts_Off
  x[1,11]=input$Timeouts_Def

  #x=data.frame(x)
  xsq=select(x,mar:timd, -dwn.1, -dwn.2, -dwn.3, -dwn.4)^2
  colnames(xsq)=paste(colnames(xsq), "sq",  sep = "_")
  xln=log(select(x,timeRemaining:timd, -closingLine, -dwn.1, -dwn.2, -dwn.3, -dwn.4))
  colnames(xln)=paste(colnames(xln), "ln",  sep = "_")
  x=cbind(x, xsq, xln)
  rm(xln, xsq)
  x
  })
  output$table <- renderDataTable(out())
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error... have you successfully run the code?

Comment: Full mesage: Warning: Error in serverFuncSource: server.R returned an object of unexpected type: list
Stack trace (innermost first):
    1: runApp
Error in serverFuncSource() : 
  server.R returned an object of unexpected type: list

Comment: Yes i did: Warning: Error in serverFuncSource: server.R returned an object of unexpected type: list
Stack trace (innermost first):
    1: runApp
Error in serverFuncSource() : 
  server.R returned an object of unexpected type: list

Comment: Do you have shiny installed? How you run the app?? What R version you have??

Comment: yes. R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21). Run app by clicking 'Run app' button in RStudio

Comment: When i run code (not run app button) the application loads, but i don't see the datatable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130655/discussion-between-aaghaz-hussain-and-user3725021).